# how to save excel sheets in a specified folder that is stored in an array

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am taking transaction details of 10 members from the database and storing it in an array. Next i am creating spreadsheet for each person and want to name dynamically by giving each person's client_id for each spreadsheet. But while saving only the last client's excel sheet is saved in the folder with name "$filename.php". How to save all the members excel sheet in the folder. Below given is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

use App\ThirdParty\CdslAuth;

global $printexl;

class MonthlyLedger extends BaseController
{

    function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function index()
    {
        
        $dbdw = \Config\Database::connect('dbdw');
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');    //get current date
        $date = $currentDate;
        $previousMonthDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime ('-1 month', strtotime($date))); 
        $startDate = date("Y-m-01", strtotime($previousMonthDate));
        $lastDate =  date("Y-m-t", strtotime($previousMonthDate)); 
        ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

        $query = $dbdw->query("SELECT DISTINCT(ACCOUNTCODE) FROM RND.TRANSACTION_DETAILS WHERE VOUCHERDATE BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$lastDate' order by ACCOUNTCODE LIMIT 10");
        $result = $query->getResult('array');
        $all_data = array_column($result, 'ACCOUNTCODE'); 
        $all_transaction = [];

        foreach ($all_data as $client_id) {
            $query = $dbdw->query("SELECT DATE(VOUCHERDATE) AS TRANSACTION_DATE,CO_CODE,NARRATION,DR_AMT,CR_AMT FROM RND.TRANSACTION_DETAILS WHERE ACCOUNTCODE = '$client_id' AND VOUCHERDATE BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$lastDate' LIMIT 20 ");
            $transaction = $query->getResult('array');
           
            $all_transaction[$client_id] = $transaction;
        }
       $exl = [];

         foreach ($all_transaction as $key_client_id => $transactions)
          {
             if (is_array($transactions)) 
             {
                 $spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
                 $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
                 $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Date');
                 $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Co-code');
                 $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Narration');
                 $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Dr-amt');
                 $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'Cr-amt');
                 $rows = 2;
                
                 for ($i = 0; $i < count($transactions); $i++) 
                 {
                     $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A' . ($i + 2), $transactions[$i]['TRANSACTION_DATE']);
                     $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B' . ($i + 2), $transactions[$i]['CO_CODE']);
                     $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C' . ($i + 2), $transactions[$i]['NARRATION']);
                     $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D' . ($i + 2), $transactions[$i]['DR_AMT']);
                     $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E' . ($i + 2), $transactions[$i]['CR_AMT']);

                 } 
             }

             else 
              {
                  echo "this is not an array";
              }

                 $filename = $key_client_id.'-TRANSACTION_DETAILS-'.'.xlsx';
                 $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
                 $exl[$key_client_id] = $spreadsheet;
```

```
type here
```

```
                 
          }

          foreach ($exl as $val)
          {
            $objWriter->save('C:\wamp64\www\bot-backend\bot-backend\monthlyLedger\$filename.xls');
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry last part of the code is in try here part.